# Docusign api authentication in production environment

Tags: docusignapi

We do have docusign api(V2) client(REST API) framework. which uses user credentials as request header value for  'X-docusign-authentication' and authenticates every request, Now that we are planning to migrate to v2.1 , Can we use same request headers and and make request to v2.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you and should you are two different things

Yes, you can and it will work.
However, using this method is highly not recommended.
This old pre-OAtuh method of sending a password as clear text on the header is insecure. The token you get does not expire and security is not robust.
DocuSign may also make changes to improve security that would require 2FA which would cause potential work to support legacy auth.
In short, yes, you can, but I recommend you seriously consider moving to the new OAuth by DocuSign.

Comment: Can you please direct me to new OAuth? It is a backend service which makes http request to docusign REST api just to download the signed docs

Comment: Token authentication is documented here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/
Since you're describing a background service that won't have a user available to authenticate when it runs, the JWT Grant would be appropriate.

Comment: You can try sample code here - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp